# Ubuntu installation stuck at logo splash screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I prepared a bootable flash disk of Ubuntu 17.10 and it was successful.

I tried installing Ubuntu on my old laptop ( HP d002tx, 4GB, i3 3rd gen) using it and it was successful without any issues. (DUAL BOOT)

but when i use the same flash disk to install Ubuntu on my new laptop ( ASUS FX553VD, 8GB, i7 7th gen) , the installation process gets stuck on Ubuntu logo in both normal installation and try without install. ( trying to DUAL BOOT, Windows 10 present, secure boot turned off)

There seems to be no problem with installation disk as it worked for the older laptop. I've even updated the BIOS of my new laptop.what can be the issue ?

Comment: Can you boot the USB to "try Ubuntu" and everything works 100% ok? Did you try any of the kernel boot codes (like noapic, nolapic, nomodeset, etc)?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, i tried both the options - " try ubuntu " and " install ubuntu " . Both of them work perfectly on the older laptop but none of them gets past the purple screen with ubuntu logo on the new laptop. 

No, i did not try any kernel boot codes. actually i am not experienced with linux i didn't know about them and how to change kernel codes.

Comment: Ok, definitely it seems that the USB itself works good, but the new laptop probably needs some "compatibility" type boot code. I might as well post an answer...

Comment: @Xen2050 please let me know if you find a solution for the problem . Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome, do remember to select a correct (check-mark) answer if one works, &/or upvote :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a kernel boot code. [Ubuntu's help page on BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) has some instructions and a nice screenshot (if you've got the default Ubuntu boot menus) for the "F6 Other Options" menu:

[image]

From a web search for your laptop's model, you might need to add `nouveau.modeset=0` manually after first pressing F6, by *"pressing ESC, whether selections were made or not, removes the popup window but opens the boot command for editing."* Just `nomodeset` will probably work too, but may have other additional undesired effects.

More Info / Related:

- [AskUbuntu Q - Graphics driver issue on Asus FX553VD and Kubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983764/graphics-driver-issue-on-asus-fx553vd-and-kubuntu-17-10)
- [Ubuntu wiki on KernelBootParameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) and setting them permanently for an installed system

Comment: I was able to complete the installation using the nouveau.modeset=0 and it successfully installed but now when i am trying to boot up Ubuntu then it again gets stuck on that purple logo screen even after it was installed. So i guess the nouveau code that i added during installation was only added temporarily . How do i permanently add that code ?

Comment: I figured that out . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `nomodeset` was the solution for me, thanks :)

Comment: Probably a litle late to the party, I think what's happening is that you are missing your graphics card driver. setting nomodeset fixes the problem temporarily and by installing the driver this problem should go away permanently.

Comment: @IandavidRodriguez I think that's true, the live ISO's can handle a lot of different hardware on their own, but there's always exceptions